# Where are the styles being defined here?

Tags: javascript, css, html

In [this Google html5slides demo](http://html5slides.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/template/index.html) there is no stylesheet inclusion and the only dependency is [this JavaScript file](http://html5slides.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/slides.js) but you are able to choose from 2 different themes and 3 different layouts.

How are you able to define these different layouts and themes? Where does the code for those sit? Also, how does the page fetch the Google logo for the following if there is no stylesheet with an `img src` for this article class:

```
<article class='biglogo'>
</article>
```

P.S Project home is http://code.google.com/p/html5slides/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply created within Javascript. For example it can easily be done using jQuery (Javascript Library) and the functions like .html, .append, .css to pretty much create whatever markup necessary.

Answer (score 1):

There are two stylesheets at the bottom of the html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:regular,semibold,italic,italicsemibold|Droid+Sans+Mono">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://html5slides.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styles.css">
```

Comment: Huh — they’re not there when I view the source of http://html5slides.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/template/index.html#1, so maybe they’re added via JavaScript.

Comment: Maybe in the generated HTML, not in the source http://code.google.com/p/html5slides/source/browse/trunk/template/index.html

Comment: Indeed. slides.js has a function `addGeneralStyle()`